# Acess violation com FindDragTarget

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Preciso detectar que tipo de componente o usuário clicou. Para isso estou usando a seguinte verificação, toda vez que o botão esquerdo do mouse é clicado:

```
if FindDragTarget(Mouse.CursorPos, True).ClassType = TEdit then
//Código
```

Porém, quando o usuário clica no teclado virtual do windows e em suas teclas, recebo a mensagem de `Access Violation`; imagino que seja por estar chamando a função mas ela não reconhecer o tipo de componente. Estou no `Windows 10` e meu `Delphi` é o `XE7`; talvez ele não reconheça o componente do teclado virtual e assim não consiga fazer a verificação. Enfim, existem outras alternativas para verificar que tipo de componente o usuário clicou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás a assumir que a função FindDragTarget(Mouse.CursorPos, True) retorna SEMPRE um valor, o que pode não estar a acontecer.

Devias fazer um check antes, algo como

```
ct:=FindDragTarget(Mouse.CursorPos, True);
if (ct<>nil) and (ct.classtype=TEdit) then
    ...
```

Comment: Obrigado, irei testar.

Comment: Funcionou, muito Obrigado.